# Handle lack of internet connection in Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am creating simple code which goes to a website, clicks on a login button, enters login details etc., and downloads data. I know this is not a recommended method, but using `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` where I `GET` the URL doesn't help as the URL of the page I finally reach, after login, has a unique authentication token generated. E.g. yesterday, `URL = www.abcd.com/ABCD-EFGH-IJKL` and today it is `URL = www.abcd.com/MNOP-QRST-UVWX`, so I don't have a set URL.
Therefore, with the `InternetExplorer.Application` method, I am trying to handle disconnections from the internet. Being disconnected from the internet, does not generate an error, but merely a blank page, so I can't use `On Error GoTo LineX`. How do I go about handling a disconnection in a code such as:

```
Dim IE as Object
Set IE = CreateObject (InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.navigate "www.abcd.com"
If 'some sort of status response' = 'some value' Then Msgbox 'You are disconnected from the internet'
Else
End If
```

Is there a status response code (as there is with `Microsoft.XMPHTTP`) which I can use to inform user with msgbox that "Please connect to the internet etc."?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with a way to get the actual HTTP response, but you could check for some sort of element on the page (or if there are elements at all), like so:

```
elements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input") 'Or whatever element will be on that page
If elements.Length = 0 Then 
    MsgBox "Please connect to the Internet."
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

This has worked nicely when I've tried it:

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/internetcheckconnection.htm